# Get cluster API url with Kubernetes client-go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I'm using client-go for Kubernetes and trying to get the API url of the current cluster, i.e. something similar to the output of `kubectl cluster-info`.
I [found](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go) a function called `getCluster`:

```
func (config *DirectClientConfig) ClientConfig() (*restclient.Config, error) {
    // check that getAuthInfo, getContext, and getCluster do not return an error.
    // Do this before checking if the current config is usable in the event that an
    // AuthInfo, Context, or Cluster config with user-defined names are not found.
    // This provides a user with the immediate cause for error if one is found
    configAuthInfo, err := config.getAuthInfo()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = config.getContext()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    configClusterInfo, err := config.getCluster()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    ...
}
```

When I write the following in my code

```
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
clusterInfo, err := config.getCluster()
```

I get the error `config.getCluster undefined (type *rest.Config has no field or method getCluster)`

How can I use this function? Is there any other way to get the this url?

Comment: What do you mean by cluster ID? `kubectl cluster-info` doesn't show any ID for me.

Comment: @savsr when I run it, the output includes the server address: `Kubernetes master is running at https://api.cluster_id.[...]` . Probably it depends on the cloud provider or something else. Sorry, I didn't think of it

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided it seems like you need to use `clusterInfo, err := config.getCluster()` instead of `configAuthInfo.getCluster()`

Comment: True, but it wouldn't work anyway, `restclient.Config` doesn't have a method `getCluster()`.

Comment: looks like you need [DirectClientConfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/77c598ed240d0c620f8443ffeb99bf46febcd52b/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ kubectl cluster-info

1. Kubernetes master is running at https://10.156.0.3:6443
2. KubeDNS is running at https://10.156.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

If you run `kubectl cluster-info -v8` you can see the following:

The first line is basicaly taken from your `~/.kube/config` file and `kubectl` just checked if it works, with the simple `GET` request, searching for something, that should be definitely present in the cluster:

```
I0222 11:21:18.015482   18150 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://10.156.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services?labelSelector=kubernetes.io%2Fcluster-service%3Dtrue
```

You can get the result of this command by starting `kubectl proxy` and then, in other console:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services?labelSelector=kubernetes.io%2Fcluster-service%3Dtrue
```

As you can see in the response, there are no lines with master URL there.

So, to get the value specified in the first line of the output of `kubectl cluster-info` you just need to read correct part of the Kubernetes config file, because you can have [several cluster configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) there.

To read and deserialize Kubernetes config file there is a function in the [loader.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/clientcmd/loader.go#L349):

```go
// LoadFromFile takes a filename and deserializes the contents into Config object
func LoadFromFile(filename string) (*clientcmdapi.Config, error)
```

or another function in the [config.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/clientcmd/config.go#L470):

```go
// getConfigFromFile tries to read a kubeconfig file and if it can't, returns an error.  One exception, missing files result in empty configs, not an error.
func getConfigFromFile(filename string) (*clientcmdapi.Config, error)
```